# dojo.js in my IBM Domino xPages app causes certain JS libraries not working

Tags: dojo, xpages

dojo.js in my xPages app causes certain JS libraries not working on page ... we use JQuery which is working fine with dojo but e.g. jquery.cookie.js (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) doesnt work when dojo.js is available. The same here for URI.js library (http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) ... its not working when dojo.js is beeing on page. To debug I have created a simple page(not xpage becase xpage includes dojo) and when dojo.js is available these libraries are not working. Removing dojo lib cause these libs working as expected.

environment: Domino 9 server means Dojo Toolkit 1.8.1

Any idea / experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with other jQuery libraries, only with jQuery Mobile and Dojo 1.8, but maybe the problem is the same and is caused by Dojo's AMD loader. Try to load the jQuery stuff before any Dojo libraries. That solved my problems.

See here for more details: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1216

Comment: Yes this (loading before dojo) helps when I experiment with this.But how can I do it on xpage? ... because links to dojo are generated automaticly and put on top in page source. If I could disabled it and load it manualy this would need to maintain correct dojo version on different servers somehow :-( Any idea here?

Comment: Please check the link in my answer. You have to add the jQuery libs in xp:headTags and enable the resource aggregation for the XPage.

Comment: Thanks, I did as in your post. Just to avoid the full aggregation, which causes some other problems, especially for CSS and links to images, I used this in XspProperties = xsp.resources.aggregate=true
, xsp.resources.aggregate.appjs=false, xsp.resources.aggregate.appcss=false . Now its working fine ... my JQuery libs are loaded before Dojo. Hopefully IBM will not change how they generate  the HTML :-) . Thanks once again Sven!

Comment: Over way would be to use jquery as a dojo module, see my reply.

Comment: I noticed your reply Egor, but I have a problem with other libraries as well e.g. URI.js library (http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/loading_jquery_with_dojo_1_7_amd_loader2?lang=en for tips on using both jQuery and Dojo

For xPages:
Add to XSP properties:

```
xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig=async:true
```

Create a script library with following content:

```
define.amd.jQuery = true;
```

and add it to your xPage as resource.

Below is the xPage code:

```
<xp:this.properties>
        <xp:parameter name="xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig" value="packages: exPackages" />
    </xp:this.properties>
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        var response = exCon.getResponse();
        var writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write("<script>\n");
        writer.write("var exPackages=[{name:'jquery',location:'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1',main:'jquery'}]\n");
        writer.write("</script>\n");
        }]]>
    </xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/jquery.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
        <xp:dojoModule name="jquery"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources><p id="test">Egor Margineanu</p>
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert($("#test").text());]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

Comment: You cannot set the djConfig with *async:true*. This won't work. If you are set the parameter on your XPage, the setting in *xsp.properties* will be ignored.

Comment: Hmm... If you are limit your solution to write the script tag for jQuery only in your beforePageLoad (without the AMD part) you would have exact the same result (but keep in mind: This is no more valid HTML). The timing issue is fixed then.

Comment: Yes, it's not really a beautiful way. My concern is that xPages engine doesn't allow 2 or more properties with same name to be defined. Also I didn't find a way how those could be somehow computed.